# submit form via AJAX method on change of select field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to send a form without leaving my current page  , so I'm using this ajaxi method furthermore i am using my submit in onchange method of Select value.but it's not work :

```
<form action="" method="post" id="rati">
 <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="rate" style="width:130px;">
  <option value="1">☆</option>
  <option value="2">☆☆</option>
  <option value="3">☆☆☆</option>
  <option value="4">☆☆☆☆</option>
  <option value="5">☆☆☆☆☆</option>
</select> 
</form>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("#rati").submit(function(e) {
            var url = "/saverate.bc?userid=18&id=122";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $("#rati").serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    $(".tnxforate").html(data)
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: why are you submitting and sending ajax at the same time?

Comment: cuz i want to view my result at the same page without leaving on

Comment: try this way https://jsfiddle.net/a5aq2kmk/1/

Comment: try using the fiddle above

Comment: Happy coding dear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not attach inline handler for this. As you are getting the response via `ajax`, there is no need to submit the form.

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("[name='rate']").on('change', function() {
    var url = "/saverate.bc?userid=18&id=122";
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: $("#rati").serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        $(".tnxforate").html(data)
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" id="rati">
  <select name="rate" style="width:130px;">
    <option value="1">☆</option>
    <option value="2">☆☆</option>
    <option value="3">☆☆☆</option>
    <option value="4">☆☆☆☆</option>
    <option value="5">☆☆☆☆☆</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: rate is name not id of select :)