# Submit ajax request form on select change wordpress

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I have a select option to filter posts by category. On select change I want the ajax request to be sent and load the posts of the category selected. I currently have this working using a submit button, but I need this to work on select option change, but I cannot get it to work just using a select.

Below is the script and form i'm working with that works on submit using a button.

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter" class="ghost-select">
            <?php
                if( $terms = get_terms( 'category', 'orderby=name' ) ) :
                    echo '<select id="categoryfilter" name="categoryfilter"><option>Select category...</option>';
                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
                        echo '<option value="' . $term->term_id . '">' . $term->name . '</option>';
                    endforeach;
                    echo '</select>';
                endif;
            ?>
            <!-- <button>Apply filter</button> -->
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="myfilter">

          <!-- onchange="this.form.submit();" -->

        </form>


$('#filter').submit(function(){
  var filter = $('#filter');

$.ajax({
    url:filter.attr('action'), // ajax
    data:filter.serialize(), // form data
    type:filter.attr('method'), // POST
    beforeSend:function(xhr){
        // filter.find('button').text('Processing...'); // changing the button label
    },
    success:function(data){
        // filter.find('button').text('Apply filter'); // changing the button label back
        $('#response').html(data); // insert data
    }
});
return false;
});
});
```

I have tired changing the initial submit function to the following, but it doesn't do anything:

```
$('#filter select').on('change', function() {
```

I've also tried adding `onchange="this.form.submit();"` to the select itself, but this submits the form and takes you away from the page to the url of the form action so I now know this isn't the right way to go.

I'm not sure what i'm missing so any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I would start by adding `preventDefault()` to your submission

Comment: so that it doesn't take you away

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35171748/submit-form-via-ajax-method-on-change-of-select-field

Comment: @Stender preventDefault did the trick! Thanks