# How can I trigger the text on the screen to change when the dropdown is pressed in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have created a combobox in HTML and i gave them a name per option. But i dont know how to trigger them when i change the value.
Here is my php code:

```
$kurlar = simplexml_load_file("https://tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml");
$dolar =$kurlar -> Currency[0] -> BanknoteBuying;
$euro = $kurlar -> Currency[3] -> BanknoteBuying;
$sterlin = $kurlar -> Currency[4] -> BanknoteBuying;
str_replace(".",",",$dolar);
str_replace(".",",",$euro);
str_replace(".",",",$sterlin);

echo "Dolar: ".$dolar;
echo "<br>";
echo "Euro : ".$euro;
echo "<br>";
echo "Sterlin: ".$sterlin;
$price = 10;
$try = $dolar * $price;
$newpriceeuro=$try/ $euro;
$newSterlinPrice = $try/$sterlin;
 echo "10 DOLAR KAÇ TL = ".$try;
 echo "10 DOLAR KAÇ EURO = ".$newpriceeuro;
 echo "10 Dolar kaç sterlin = ".$newSterlinPrice;
```

Here is my HTML:

```
 <select name="currency">
    <option value="dolar" name="dolar">$ USD</option>
    <option value="euro" name="euro">€ EUR</option>
<option value="try" name ="try">₺ TRY</option>
```

Here is my control PHP code after html:

```
if(isset($_POST["euro"]))
    {
        $v1 = $_POST["euro"];
        echo $v1;
    }
```

Does anybody answer my question?

Comment: Note: per https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php you will need to assign the return value of `str_replace` to a variable like `$dolar = str_replace(".",",",$dolar);`.

Comment: One way to achieve this functionality could be to trigger an AJAX request to a separate PHP script that would load the XML file, parse it, and return the converted value. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35171748/submit-form-via-ajax-method-on-change-of-select-field should give you a decent start. You could pass the `value` as a GET parameter dynamically (in JS), so you could make a request to `/load-currency.php?type=euro` so your PHP script knows which currency to return.

Comment: when i load the XML file, Will it pull the current exchange rates?

Comment: Though a simpler way would be to trigger a page reload when the user submits the form, and then your existing PHP should work. You will need to wrap your `select` in a form tag `<form method="post"><select>...</select><button>Convert</button></form>` which will submit the POST data (`$_POST['currency']`) back to this page with one of the values `dolar`, `euro`, or `try`

Comment: if that's what the XML file contains, then yes. The XML gets parsed whenever this PHP script runs, which is presumably when the web page loads.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you **can't use** *PHP* (BACK END) to trigger **a client action** you should use *Javascript* (FRONT END)

Comment: Don't post comments as answers. If you don't have enough rep to comment, work on that first. Answers are reserved for actual *solutions*. Commenting is a privilege and trying to bypass the rep restrictions like this is *not* a good way to earn rep, rather the opposite.